# TypeError: Object of type OTP is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm getting an error: `Object of type OTP is not JSON serializable`. It might be `OTP` data not converted to JSON data while parsing but I'm not pretty sure.
If anyone could figure out where I'm doing thing wrong then would be much appreciated. thank you so much in advance.

`views.py`

```py
class SendOTPForMobileRegistrationAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        phone_number = request.data['phone_number']
        country_code = request.data['country_code']
        
        if phone_number and country_code:
            user_newqs = User.objects.filter(phone_number__iexact=phone_number, country_code__iexact=country_code)
            if user_newqs.exists():
                user_newobj = user_newqs.first()       
                if user_newobj:
                    #Production    
                    code = generateOTP()
                    subject = 'Emojizone (OTP Verification)'
                    message = 'Your One Time Password For Verification is : {}'.format(code)
                    
                    formatted_mobile = '+{}{}'.format(country_code,phone_number)
                    print('formatted_mobile',formatted_mobile)

                    client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
                    try:
                        message = client.messages.create(body=message,from_='+13864909283',to=formatted_mobile)
                    except:
                        return Response({
                            'success': 'False',
                            'message': 'Please provide valid mobile number 1'
                    },status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST) 

                    current_time = make_aware(datetime.now())
                    future_time = current_time + timedelta(minutes=30)
                    otp_created = OTP.objects.create(otp=code,user=user_newobj)
                    otp_created.save()
    
                    return Response({'success': 'True',
                                     'message': 'OTP has been successfully sent to your registered mobile number',
                                     'phone_number': user_newobj.phone_number,
                                     'country_code': user_newobj.country_code,
                                     'email': user_newobj.email,
                                     'otp_created': otp_created},
                                    status=HTTP_200_OK)
                else:
                    return Response({
                        'success': 'False',
                        'message': 'Wrong Credentials',
                    },status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                            
            else:
                return Response({'success': 'False',
                                 'message': 'User with this number does not exist',
                    
                },status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)     
        else:
            return Response({
                'success': 'False',
                'message': 'Please provide mobile number and country code'
            },status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: `otp_created` created needs to be serialized

Comment: @ArakkalAbu  Yes! you're right. i made a silly mistake. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This would be more like for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), but here's a tip how to structure your code a bit better. On top you have three nested `if` statements which make your code indented a lot:

```
if phone_number and country_code:            
    user_newqs = User.objects.filter(phone_number__iexact=phone_number, country_code__iexact=country_code)
        if user_newqs.exists():
            user_newobj = user_newqs.first()       
                if user_newobj:
                    # here goes successful logic
```

but when you want to see what happens when a condition is not fulfilled (eg. `if phone_number and country_code:`), you have to scroll a lot to see that it goes nowhere and it only returns HTTP 400. It's better to reverse the logic - put the dead-end on top, so you know the code below is going towards successful dispatching without any need to branch the logic via if/else.  Nice side-effect is that your code will be less indented. Example:

```
if not (phone_number and country_code): 
    return Response({
        'success' : 'False',
        'message' : 'Please provide mobile number and country code'
    },status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)  

if not user_newqs.exists():
    return Response({'success' : 'False',
                     'message' : 'User with this number does not exist',
        
    },status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

if not user_newobj:
   return Response({
        'success' : 'False',
        'message' : 'Wrong Credentials',
    },status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


# all error-states handled above, no need for any `else:` or code nesting/indenting.
```